# Prime ideal contains an integer

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

If $P$ is a non-zero prime ideal inside the ring of integers for some number field $L$, I want to show that $P$ contains a rational integer. My idea was to take some $x$ in $P$ and look at its norm (which is an integer). But I don't know how to show that this norm is in $P$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the characteristic polynomial $Q_a$ of an element $a$, that is 
$Q_a(X)= \prod_{i=1}^n(X - \sigma_i(a)) = \sum_{i=0}^n b_i X^i$ where $\sigma_i$ are all embeddings of $L$.

Recall that this is an integral polynomial and  its constant coefficient $b_0$ is $(-1)^n$ times the norm of $a$.

On the other hand as $a$ is a root of $Q_a$ one has $-b_0 = \sum_{i=1}^n b_i a^i = a( \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} b_i a^{i-1}) $.

In particular in the ring of algebraic integers the norm of $a$ is a multiple of $a$; recall that the $b_i$ are all rational integers.

Now if $a$ is in an ideal $P$, then every multiple of $a$ is also in $P$; thus $b_0$ and hence $(-1)^n b_0$, that is the norm of $a$, are also in $P$.

I believe you do not need that the ideal is prime.

The other thing is that it always contains $0$, so literally as asked the question has an easier answer. 
In fact for prime ideals one can show that the contain exactly one prime number. Maybe this is what you are ultimately after.

Comment: Thanks. But the norm is the product of the complex embeddings of $x$, which lie in $\mathbb{C}$ not in the original ring. So it doesn't really make sense to say that $\sigma_1(x)\in P$ since $P$ and $\mathbb{C}$ are completely different spaces.

Comment: Let me think about it. At least the argument should work if the extension is Galois as then all the conjugates are in L. But that's likely not the way to go.

Comment: I expanded the answer. Thanks for pointing out the gap. I hope it is fine now.